# Encoded Absolute URL missing last character

Tags: sharepoint-designer, url

I'm trying to get the encoded absolute URL for a newsfeed post. however if the Title of the newsfeed post has a special character at the end, eg ! (exclamation point), it does not include that to an hyperlink in Sharepoint Designer.

example:

https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/Lists/NewsFeed/HelloWorld!

it only makes the link without the ! (exclamation point), hence when the recipient of the link in email clicks on it, it does not go to the actual URL

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: I tried using Workflow Context -> Current Item URL. but this does not work for us since we want the view to be like a certain newsfeed view and not item level view.